# c++ 03 class template Is this a conversion constructor or conversion operator? and how to declare the method to solve this?

Tags: c++, templates, type-conversion, operator-overloading, constructor-overloading

i have problem to make it work in this line
  Polynomial p2( pf_1 );

i don't know is conversion constructor or conversion operator and how to deal with different type template but same size

```
    std::cout << "-------- " << __func__ << " --------\n";
    Polynomial<float,2> pf_1;
    pf_1[0] = 1.1;
    pf_1[1] = -2.2;
    pf_1[2] = 1.1;
    std::cout << pf_1 << std::endl;

    Polynomial<int,2> p2( pf_1 ); // convert
    std::cout << p2 << std::endl;

template< typename T, int N > 
class Polynomial
{
  public:
    friend std::ostream& operator<< <T, N>( std::ostream &out, Polynomial<T, N> const& pol );
    Polynomial();
    T& operator[](int pos);


    T GetDegree(int pos)const;
    void SetDegree(int pos, T value);

  private:
    T coeff[N];

};
```

from (float)
1.1 -2.2*x^1 +1.1*x^2

convert to (int)

1 -2*x^1 +x^

Comment: You're asking anyone that wants to use your code as an example to answer your question to write a whole lot of scaffolding that you really should have provided or left out since it is irrelevant. Read through [mcve] and update your example to be actual compilable (other than the part you do not know how to fix) code. Also, `pf_1[2]` is out of bounds.

Comment: nope for this case, 
Polynomial<float,2> will construct 3 array of float and init all to 0

where index represent the exp power

Comment: @clarenceng Not with the member definition `T coeff[N];`. If you had `T coeff[N+1];` that would be fine.

Comment: Your terminology for `GetDegree` and `SetDegree` is unusual. Normally we say a polynomial has one "degree" and a number of "coefficients".

Comment: the GetDegree and SetDegree i use to by pass this 

Polynomial<int,4> p4 = p3*p1;

where i make  * operator as binary operator


  std::cout << "-------- " << __func__ << " --------\n";
    Polynomial<int,3> p3;
    p3[0] = 1;
    p3[1] = 1;
    p3[2] = 1;
    p3[3] = 1; // defines 1+x+x^2+x^3

    Polynomial<int,1> p1;
    p1[0] = 1;
    p1[1] = -1; // defines 1-x
    std::cout << p1 << std::endl;

    Polynomial<int,4> p4 = p3*p1;
    std::cout << p4 << std::endl; // produces 1+ -1 * x^4
                                  // (1+x+x^2+x^3)*(1-x) = 1-x^4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either a converting constructor or a conversion operator could work here. But when both are possible, the converting constructor is usually more straightforward.

So you want a single type like `Polynomial<int, 2>` to be convertible from a family of other types including `Polynomial<double, 2>` and `Polynomial<short int, 2>`. This suggest you want not just a simple converting constructor, but a member template constructor. The degree `N` should stay the same as the class template, but we introduce a new type parameter for the source coefficient type:

```
template< typename T, int N >
class Polynomial
{
public:
    template< typename U >
    explicit Polynomial(const Polynomial<U, N>& src);
    // ...
};
```

I've marked it `explicit`, which will support your `Polynomial<int,2> p2( pf_1 );` example, but forbid implicit conversions. This is up to you, but implicit conversions can sometimes lead to unfortunate surprises.

If the constructor template will be defined outside the class template, note you need to list the class template parameters and then the member template parameters to write the definition:

```
template< typename T, int N > template< typename U >
Polynomial<T, N>::Polynomial(const Polynomial<U, N>& src) : // ...
```

Comment: i got strange behavior as because N is 1 size smaller, it will just construct N size...

Comment: If `N` is the polynomial degree, make sure the member is `T coeff[N+1];` so the object can store all `N+1` coefficients.